# PC builder for PT

Tags: equipment

I will soon be in the market for a new pc to run protools 10.
Is there any good companies in the UK that build a PC for protools?
Using the correct motherboard for PT and quiet power supply /tower etc.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.aria.co.uk/Systems/Home+and+Office/Audio+Workstations/

Aria do some here that look pretty acceptable- never got one either. I'd have a long hard think about this or a mac pro though for this price range. You get much more bang for your buck with a PC which im always tempted by but macs are great for Pro tools.

My advice would be to not use a PC for audio unless it's going to stay offline. In my experience a couple of random updates and all sorts of weird thigs happen! Macs seem a bit more forgiving in this area.

Answer (score 0):

http://3xs.scan.co.uk/Category.asp?SystemMasterCategoryID=2

Comment: any idea if a company like this exist in the US?  PCs built for pro audio?

Comment: @Michael Yes, ADK: http://www.adkproaudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

Digital Village (dv247.com) does this: http://www.dv247.com/synergy/buy/. Never seen one, can't vouch for it but I'd hope they know what they're doing...

Hope that helps!